# Getting an output error with command head in shell script

Tags: shell-script

getting an error with head command. There are two files with size 48bytes in directory and its printing once along with the directory path instead of twice. Why the head command is not considering the first two files i.e `head -n 2`? Is there any other method to do?

My code:

```
find "$dir" -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -n -r | head -n 2|
             {
              read -r file dir
              printf "size: %d\n\t%s\n" "$file" "$dir"
              }
```

My output error:

```
size: 48
      testdir/file7.txt
```

The testdir directory contains two files with same size 48 but throwing only once along with directory path instead of twice

My desired output:

```
size: 48
      testdir/file7.txt
      testdir/file1.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no error with `head -n 2`; you can check that by removing the `|` and the subsequent code.

The problem is that the code between the braces is only executed once - it's not a loop. And `read` only reads data from a single line of input. So you need to make some sort of loop to print data for multiple files.

You could use a `while` loop, or you could take advantage of the built-in loop of awk to read & print the data. Eg, the awk command below only prints the size info if the size of the current file is different to the size of the previous file.

```awk
awk 'BEGIN{size=-1}; {if($1!=size){size=$1; printf "size: %d\n", size}; printf "\t%s\n", $2}'
```

We don't *really* need to explicitly initialize `size`, since it's automatically initialized to the empty string, but it's nice to be explicit about these things, IMHO.

---

That awk command replaces the

```bash
{
    read -r file dir
    printf "size: %d\n\t%s\n" "$file" "$dir"
}
```

section of your code. In other words, you can use

```bash
find "$dir" -type f -printf '%s %p\n' |
sort -n -r | head -n 2 |
awk 'BEGIN{size=-1}; 
{if($1!=size){size=$1; printf "size: %d\n", size}; 
printf "\t%s\n", $2}'
```

You can put it all on one line, or split it over multiple lines. It's also possible to put the awk program into its own file, but there's no need to do that for such a tiny program.

Note that you can make the `-n` option to `head` as large as you like, and the awk program will behave as expected. Also note that awk is *very* fast - it's much more efficient than using `read` and `printf`.

FWIW, awk code for simple text processing is often significantly faster than equivalent Python code, so even though many consider awk to be antiquated it's still quite popular.

---

To print the data for **only** the largest file(s) in a directory, you can do this:

```bash
find . -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | 
sort -nr | 
awk 'NR==1{size=$1;printf "size: %d\n", size};
$1!=size{exit};
{printf "\t%s\n", $2}'
```

The `NR==1` says to execute the following block (the stuff inside the `{}`) only when the Number of the Record equal 1 - a record is just a line. So we get the size of the first file, which is the largest file (thanks to the preceding`sort` command), save it in the `size` variable, and then print the size.

`$1!=size{exit}` says to exit the program as soon as we read a line where the data in the 1st field doesn't match what we've saved in the `size` variable.

The last block  `{printf "\t%s\n", $2}` prints the pathname for each file.

---

There are various ways to print both the largest and smallest files found by the `find` command. One way would be to read all the data into awk, storing it in an array, sort the array, and then print the data for the files of maximum & minimum size. But I'm going to adopt a simpler strategy here, and re-cycle my existing code. To do this more efficiently, I'll put the awk program into a file. Save this file to a directory in your command PATH and give it execute permission.

**field1match.awk**

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# print only the records whose 1st field matches that of the 1st record
# Written by PM 2Ring 2015.05.21

NR==1{size=$1; printf "size: %d\n", size}
$1!=size{exit}
{printf "\t%s\n", $2}
```

And here's the command line which uses `tee` to duplicate the output from `find` and then sort it and print it using process substitution:

```bash
find "$dir" -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | 
tee > >(sort -n | field1match.awk) >(sort -rn | field1match.awk)
```

Comment: so you mean to say instead of the whole code of mine i have to you use yours.

Comment: @buddhasreekanth: My awk code just replaces your `read... printf` block. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your code working perfectly. could you please explain your code briefly.I dont want to use `head` command. If i do so, how come it will gives automatically file size.

Comment: @buddhasreekanth: If you don't want to use the `head` command why is it in the command line you originally posted??? `head` simply prints the first _n_ lines of a file or stdin (with _n_ being 10 by default, unless you change that using the `-n` option). The file size and pathname data are being generated by the `find` command, specifically the `%s` and `%p` formatting commands in `find`'s `-printf` option. `sort -n -r` sorts that data line by line, in reverse numeric order. And then `head` controls how many lines of that data are printed. (to be continued).

Comment: @buddhasreekanth: To understand how awk works, please see the awk man page. But briefly, awk reads input & performs specified actions on it. By default, it operates line by line. awk can automatically split the words in the input line into variables with numeric names. `$0` is the whole input line, `$1` is the 1st word, `$2` is the 2nd word, etc. It can also use named variables. So my awk code tests the1st word on each input line (which contains the file size) & if it's different to the 1st word from the previous line, it gets printed. And then the pathname gets printed.

Comment: because I thought the `head` command was problem to my code. I was enhnacing my code bit to a bit. I dont want to use `head` command but the code should display size of file automatically. Is it possible? if so,please let me know

Comment: @buddhasreekanth: So get rid of the `head` command! As I explained earlier, it's the `find` command that's generating the size info. `head` is just blindly copying lines of input.

Comment: Thats fine. for example, if a directory(say /path/file/test) has 5 files among the 4 files are of same size and largest files. i need those files to be display. If i change the directory path(say mypath/to/life has 10 files , 6 files are same size and largest size) while executing script with irrespective of directory path it should display all largest files sizes. How to do that?

Comment: @buddhasreekanth: Do you mean you **only** want the largest files to be printed?

Comment: Ya along with the directory path. if i excute the directory(mypath/to/file) with script, it should display all largest files with path in that directory. If i change the directory to another (say /myfile/path), should displays all largest file. Hope you got me.

Comment: @buddhasreekanth: I'll add some new code to my answer.

Comment: your code is awesome and working perfectly to my requirements. many thanks. What if i want for smallest files also

Comment: To **only** print the smallest files remove the `-r` option from the `sort` command; the awk command needs no changes. To print the largest files followed by the smallest files you _could_ run the original command followed by the version using `sort -n`, but that's inefficient, since it has to scan the directory twice with `find`. Fortunately, there's a simple way to process the output of `find` multiple times. I'll add some more code to my answer. But in future, please ask a new question when you think up new requirements after your question's already been answered.

Comment: I done with smallest file sizes and  already removed `-r` in the `sort ` command. What about the average file size in a directory? how to do that?

Comment: @buddhasreekanth:  Please ask a new question.